# FragmentPagerAdapter - On the left always same Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

How can I use the `ViewPager` view with `FragmentPagerAdapter` to do the following?

There is a list of several fields (=> `Fragment`s) where the first field plays a special role.
If I scroll to the next item it should show the next item until the end of the list (usual behavior).
If I scroll to the previous item it should show always the first field and there should be no possibility to scroll further to the left. Also the fragments right to this special field shall be "reset" (state as it was at the beginning).

Comment: Where is the code you have written for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Check condition onPageChangeListner();

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       //check your condition here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```